# exclude a path from vuex-oidc in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using below code to create my vue app routes and [vuex-oidc](https://github.com/perarnborg/vuex-oidc) `vuexOidcCreateRouterMiddleware` to protect them.

My routes are not only in this file. I'm using `axios` in `App.vue` to get other routes from an api endpoint and add them to routes using `this.$router.addRoute()`

When these extra routes are loaded `beforeEach` applied vuex-oidc to all routes.

Up to this point all works perfectly.

My problem is

I need to **exclude** `"Welcome"` route so `vuex-oidc` will not be applied to it. So it will be accessible to all visitors not only logged-in users.

**How can i edit following line to exclude Welcome route?**

`router.beforeEach(vuexOidcCreateRouterMiddleware(store, 'oidcStore'))`

**or any other solution.**

Thanks

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { vuexOidcCreateRouterMiddleware } from 'vuex-oidc'
import store from '@/store'
const routes = [
    {
        path: process.env.BASE_URL + 'oidc-callback',
        name: 'OidcCallback',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "OidcCallback" */ '../views/OidcCallback.vue')
    },
    {
        path: process.env.BASE_URL + 'profile',
        name: 'Profile',
        component: () => import('../views/Profile.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: process.env.BASE_URL + 'oidc-silent-renew',
        name: 'OidcSilentRenew',
        component: () => import('../views/OidcSilentRenew.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: process.env.BASE_URL + 'welcome',
        name: 'Welcome',
        component: () => import('../views/Welcome.vue'),
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    base: '/vue3/',
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
router.beforeEach(vuexOidcCreateRouterMiddleware(store, 'oidcStore'))

export default router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was overlooking. Solution is very simple. Just add `isPublic` and set it to `true` under `meta` in `route`

```
const routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: process.env.BASE_URL + 'welcome',
        name: 'Welcome',
        component: () => import('../views/Welcome.vue'),
        meta: {
            isPublic: true
        }
    },
    ...
]
```